# How to modify a cell of UITableView from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In VC#1, I have a UITableView. When I tap on a cell, I am brought to VC#2 where information about that cell is displayed.

I want to be able to press a button in VC#2 which changes the title of the cell it corresponds with in VC#1, but I am confused on how to do this?

Should I create a variable in VC#2 to save the indexPath for the cell that was tapped, and then call a function in VC#1 from VC#2 that uses that indexPath to update the cell? If I did this, wouldn't VC#1 need to be static so I know I'm modifying the right instance of VC#1? I'm using a push segue and a navigation controller to go back, so creating a new instance of VC#1 wouldn't reference the same VC im trying to modify as I believe?

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the delegate pattern.

VC1 should know what cell that VC2 is showing. You should have an `IndexPath` property in VC1 that stores what cell is VC2 currently displaying, right?

Now, create a protocol called `VC2Delegate`:

```
protocol VC2Delegate : class {
    func titleDidChange(_ vc2: VC2, to title: String)
}
```

Now, add this property in VC2:

```
weak var delegate: VC2Delegate?
```

Now, when you think the title of the cell should change, call the delegate:

```
delegate?.titleDidChange(self, to: "Some Title")
```

That's all for VC2.

Make VC1 conform to `VC2Delegate`:

```
extension VC1: VC2Delegate {
    func titleDidChange(_ vc2: VC2, to title: String) {
        // set the text of the table cell here...
    }
}
```

Now, when you are passing data to VC2 from VC1, probably in the `prepareForSegue` method, do

```
vc2.delegate = self
```

Learn more about delegates [here](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef).

Comment: I was about to suggest the same answer. The answer is well written!

Comment: @Shebuka VC1 should have that information when it is about to present VC2, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for this! One question, when I implement the delegate method in VC1, how do I know the indexPath of the cell that was selected so that I can update the title? I tried using indexPathForSelectedRow, but it seems after I navigated to VC2, that was forgotten.

Comment: @Brejuro I suppose you are presenting VC2 when the user taps on a cell? You need to declare an `IndexPath` property in VC1, and set it in the `didSelectRowAt` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass every data you want through view controllers using delegates

*First create a protocol whatever you want*

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate {

   func getSelected(value:Int)

}
```

*Create a variable from your ViewController you want pass the data*

```
var delegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
```

*On didSelectRowAt method you will do*

```
if delegate != nil {
   delegate.getSelected(value: indexPath.row)
}

self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

*On ViewController that will receive data you have to do this*

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {

      vc.delegate = self

   }

}

extension YourViewController: ViewControllerDelegate {

   fun getSelected(value:Int) {

      // Get value from another view controller and manage it

   } 

}
```

This code is in Swift 4

If you don't understand something let me know

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong approach you are pursuing. You must separate your data layer from your presentation layer. So in VC#2 you edit your visualized data, then VC#1 reloads the data to update its view.

Comment: Ah okay, but how would I edit the cell in VC#2 then? Would I need a reference to the cell, or to the tableview and indexpath?

Comment: This is your duty as developer to project an underneath data structure. Like f.e. an array of objects and when click on cell of VC#1 it tells to VC#2 the index of the object, then VC#2 populates it fileds with data from array knowing it's index, when you update the data you broadcast a notification about the change and VC#1 updates the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You should not do that at all.

View controllers should not modify other view controller's views.

You should modify the data model in VC2, then send a message back to VC1 telling it to update the cell.

(In the push segue you can set up VC1 to be VC2's delegate, then define a protocol that VC2 uses to notify VC1 about the indexPath's of the data model that need to be updated.)