# How to create an class object in different class

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to update my UITableView in class A from different class B

**What code I have I my first main VC class:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let networkService = NetworkService()
    let cellTable = ChooseCurrencyViewController()
    
    var response: Currency? = nil
    var newValue: String? = nil
    
    @IBOutlet weak var getData: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityData: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    
    
    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let urlString = "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js"
        
        activityData.startAnimating()
        startButton.isHidden = true
    
        networkService.request(urlString: urlString) { (currency, error) in
            guard currency != nil else { return }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.setupInterface()
            }
            currency?.valute.map({ (first, second) in
                self.newValue = first
                print(self.newValue ?? "no value")
            })
            
            self.response = currency
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func setupInterface() {
        activityData.isHidden = true
        startButton.isHidden = false
        getData.text = "Данные получены"
    }
    
}
```

**And there's my second VC class with UITableView:**

```
class ChooseCurrencyViewController: UIViewController {

    let tableCell = ViewController()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    
    
    
    private func setupTableView() {
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTableView()
        
    }

}

extension ChooseCurrencyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableCell.newValue?.count ?? 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "123"
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

The program just crashes when I'm trying to build it.

Also I'm pretty sure that there's another way to update my UITableView, if anyone can help me with it, that would be really great.

**What do I want to do with my table is:** set the number of rows in UITableView of .count of my **key** getting from **[key, value]** from JSON.

I'm new to programming and swift language also, please give some advice.

Comment: The default initializer `ViewController()` creates a brand new instance of the controller which is not the instance in the storyboard. You need the actual reference with segue or instantiation from the storyboard. Besides you are strongly discouraged from getting the data source directly from an different view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use protocol that gives new value in viewcontroller to choosecurrencyvc. There is already explanation for similar to this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48506190/14098735